# What is the alternative of findcontrol command from webforms in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, webforms

I'm new to working with Asp.Net MVC coming from WebForms. As a beginner of this programming pattern (MVC) it just made my mind blown-off. I find hard to handle complexity on this programming pattern. My task right now is to capture the value of the inputbox from a nested looped table in a view so I can assign it in the actionresult method of my controller. The reason why I need to capture the values of the inputbox inside nested loop table because in my action method I need to databind or make a query using linq-sql with where clause and assign the value of the captured inputbox value to the where clause. That's why I need to find the alternative of a "findcontrol" command from the webforms perspective to capture the value of a control. So if somebody here is familiar with working on Gridview using findcontrol command in webforms,that is the alternative here is what I'm looking for. How to do this in Asp.net MVC? So far, when I open this view I've got a runtime error saying :
***The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'comid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PostComment(Int32)' in 'MyFirstMVCApp.Controllers.ProfileController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters***

**View:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{   
      <table>     
@foreach (var item in Model.Comments )
{
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="editor-field" style="display:none; margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:10px">
   // I need to capture the value of this inputbox into my action method controller
         <input type="text" id="comidvalue" name="comid" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Id)" />

        </div>

         <div style="font-weight:bold;">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) </div> 

  <p style ="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :500px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comment) </p>
  <p style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:0px"> <input type="button" id="like" name="like" value="Like" style="color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /> <input type="button" id="Reply" name="Reply" value="Replie(s)" style="color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /></p>

          <div id="divrep" style="position:relative;left:50px; overflow:auto;margin-top:0px">
             <table>
             @for(int i=0;i<Model.Replies.Count;i++)
              {
                 <tr>
                     @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Comments[i].Id)
                     <td>
                     <p style ="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :445px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF;">@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Replies[i].reply)  </p>
                           <br />


                   </td>
                 </tr>
              } 
            </table>


         </div> 

           <input type="text" id="namerep" name="namerep" />
       <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="namerep" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                         <br />
              <textarea id="reply" name="reply" style="width:500px;height:100px;resize:none" ></textarea>
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="reply" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

    <br />
           <input type="submit" value="Post Reply" name="butname" />

        </td>


    </tr>

}

</table>


      }
```

**Controller:**

```
// this int comid variable is the one I expect from the captured value of the inputbox
    public ActionResult PostComment(int comid) 
        {

            var vModel = new CreateViewModel();

            vModel.Comments = comrepository.GetAllComments().ToList();

            vModel.Reply = replyrepository.GetReplybyID(comid);


            return View(vModel); 
        }
```

**Model:**

```
 public class CommentModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

     //   [Required(ErrorMessage="Don't miss to put your name.")]
        public string name { get; set; }

      //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Don't leave your comments empty.")]
        public string comment { get; set;}


    }

    public class ReplyModel
    {
        public int idrep { get; set; }
        public string namerep { get; set; }
        public string reply { get; set; }
    } 

    public class CreateViewModel
    {
        public CommentModel CreateComment { get; set; } // this line is optional
        public ReplyModel CreateReply { get; set; }
        public List<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
        public List<ReplyModel> Replies { get; set; }
        public ReplyModel Reply { get; set; }
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
 public IEnumerable<ReplyModel> GetReplybyID(int Id)
          {
              List<ReplyModel> profiles = new List<ReplyModel>();
              var prof = from profile in Reprepository.RepTabs
                          where profile.Id == Id
                         orderby profile.Id descending
                         select profile;
              var user = prof.ToList();
              foreach (var item in user)
              {
                  profiles.Add(new ReplyModel()
                  {
                      idrep = item.Id,
                      namerep = item.Name,
                      reply = item.Replies

                  });
              }
              return profiles;
          }
```

Comment: Each row of your table contains `<input name="comid"...>`. Which one are you expecting to get?

Comment: since `comid` parameter in the controller can't be null, you need to include the `comid` value in the url when opening the view, i.e `/Profile/PostComment/1`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need to capture all different inputbox values in all rows for databinding in my action method controller. Is this posible here in MVC? because I have done it in webforms by using findcontrol command in the grid.

Comment: @ekad How do I implement that in my controller?

Comment: Yes its possible, but you need to post back you whole model (not just a single value) and you need to render your controls in a for loop (as per your second loop) using strongly types html helpers so the inputs are correctly named for postback. You need to post you model and the GET method.

Comment: @timmack when you got that error, what was the url in your browser? Was it `mydomain.com/Profile/PostComment`? If so, it must be `mydomain.com/Profile/PostComment/x` where x is the `comid` value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is like pulling my leg. Isn't it? Well I'm not sure how to do that if I understood it correctly. I'm blown away with this programming pattern. Not developer friendly!

Comment: @timmack Did you get that error when you opened the view, or when you clicked the `Post Reply` button?

Comment: @ekad Yes I got those runtime error saying the comid is null, meaning it was not captured because it's in the loop of the nested table.

Comment: @timmack, Once you understand the basics of MVC, that's what you will be saying about web forms.

Comment: @ekad I got the error when you opened the view so apparently you can't click the POst Reply button

Comment: @timmack do you require the `comid` value when opening the view?

Comment: @ekad Yes I need the value of the comid to be captured so that I can do the databinding which represents all the replies in the view. Take a look on the view and the controller I posted.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Apparently this pattern is most difficult programming pattern I encountered. Since I guess you are veteran with this pattern. What is the best tip to learn this methodology?

Comment: @timmack, Start by working through the tutorials on the [MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc). From what you have posted its not even clear what you trying to do. Is the controller method a GET or POST method. Your need to include them both.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I believe my controller is GET method because I'm displaying the data which are comments and replies respectively on a single view.

Comment: @timmack Can you edit your question and include the code of `CreateViewModel`?

Comment: @timmack see my answer below, it should eliminate the error when you open the view, but there's still more things to do after that. I'll update the answer after you confirm that the error is gone and the view is displayed correctly.

Comment: @ekad...This was my first code I used and has no error and display all the comments in the view. However, I need the replies to be databinded in order for me to display the replies as well along with each comments. Now, no error but replies are not displaying since you remove the comid parameters and the code to supposedly displays the replies which is this one vModel.Reply = replyrepository.GetReplybyID(comid); Can you please update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get anything from the view while you're in a controller get action method because the view isn't rendered yet. What you need to do in the controller get action method is passing all information that's needed in the view using a model variable.

Looks like you get the error because you open the view by using this url: `/Profile/PostComment` while the `PostComment` get action method requires an integer parameter that can't be null.

Based on the discussion, you want to display replies for each comment, so `Replies` property should be in `CommentModel` instead of `CreateViewModel`. Change your model to this

```
public class CommentModel
{
    public CommentModel()
    {
        this.Replies = new List<ReplyModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

 //   [Required(ErrorMessage="Don't miss to put your name.")]
    public string name { get; set; }

  //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Don't leave your comments empty.")]
    public string comment { get; set;}

    public List<ReplyModel> Replies { get; set; }
}

public class CreateViewModel
{
    public CreateViewModel()
    {
        this.Comments = new List<CommentModel>();
    }

    public CommentModel CreateComment { get; set; } // this line is optional
    public ReplyModel CreateReply { get; set; }
    public List<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
    public ReplyModel Reply { get; set; }
}
```

The `comid` parameter in your controller method needs to be removed because it's actually in `Comments` property of your model. You can get the replies by looping through `vModel.Comments`

```
public ActionResult PostComment()
{
    var vModel = new CreateViewModel();
    vModel.Comments = comrepository.GetAllComments().ToList();

    // loop through vModel.Comments
    for (int i = 0; i < vModel.Comments.Count; i++)
    {
        vModel.Comments[i].Replies = replyrepository.GetReplybyID(vModel.Comments[i].Id).ToList();
    }

    return View(vModel); 
}
```

In your view, change this part

```
@for(int i=0;i<Model.Replies.Count;i++)
{
     <tr>
         @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Comments[i].Id)
         <td>
         <p style ="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :445px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF;">@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Replies[i].reply)  </p>
               <br />


       </td>
     </tr>
}
```

to this

```
@for (int i = 0; i < item.Replies.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Id)
        <td>
        <p style ="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; max-width :445px; min-height :5px;  display :block; background-color: #CCCCFF;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.Replies[i].reply)  </p>
        <br />


        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @ekad...This was my first code I used and has no error and display all the comments in the view. However, I need the replies to be databinded in order for me to display the replies as well along with each comments. Now, no error but replies are not displaying since you remove the comid parameters and the code to supposedly displays the replies which is this one vModel.Reply = replyrepository.GetReplybyID(comid);

Comment: Can you update the question and add the code of `replyrepository.GetReplybyID` method? If you want to display all replies for each comment, I think there should be a repository method that returns multiple replies based on a comment id. I'm not sure why `replyrepository.GetReplybyID` returns only one reply.

Comment: The `Id` parameter in your repository code isn't used at all, are you sure about that? If so, then the parameter can be removed and you can add `vModel.Replies = replyrepository.GetReplybyID();` in your controller.

Comment: I think what you need in `replyrepository.GetReplybyID` method is something like `from rep in Reprepository.RepTabs where rep.CommentId == Id select rep`.

Comment: if you remove the Id param in replyrepository.GetReplybyID(int Id) you can't use the where clause so how come?Please see my updated repository in the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62156/discussion-between-ekad-and-timmack).